# Html Audio in Android Webview

Tags: java, android, html

I am a beginner in HTML and Java and I am attempting to play audio files in a simple web app on the android through the Web view using HTML and Java. I have succeeded in getting this to work on Android 4.0. It however will not work on 2.3.3 or 2.2. I've done a lot of researching and so far all I have found is that it is not supported. Can anyone confirm or deny this and possibly point me in the right direction? Here is what I have working on 4.0 but nothing else.

```java
WebView engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);

String audioTest =  "< html >" + <br/>
                "< body >" + <br/>
                "< audio id='egSound' preload='auto'  autoplay ='autoplay'>" + <br/>
                "< source src=' www.egSoundUrl.com '>" +                    
                "< /audio>" + <br/>
                "< /body>"  +  
                "< /html>";

engine.loadData(audioTest, "text/html", null);
```

How can I get the same code to work for 2.3.3? In my research I came across someone who was able to play the audio file using the video tag, but I was unable to get that working. Any shared knowledge will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Yep. Sadly HTML5 audio element is supported only from Gingerbread.

I read that the audio tag IS supported someway in 2.2 & 2.3, but for some very weird reason the mp3 & ogg codecs are not. Therefore, even if it's supported is useless on phones up to Android 2.3.

**SOLUTION 1**
The video tag workaround (1.6 to 2.2) is the following:

```
<video src="soundfile.mp3" onclick="this.play();"></video>
```

is the one you tried?

**SOLUTION 2**
Another possible solution (2.2+) is to implement a JQuery Player with Flash fallback, like [UbaPlayer](http://www.brianhadaway.com/ubaplayer-the-jquery-html5-audio-player-with-flash-fallback/).

**SOLUTION 3**
Lastly.. there's a java workaround by another user of StackOverflow, here:

- [HTML5 audio tag on Android - answer by mdelolmo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4896110/1614381)

..Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick one-liner for any new visitors - try using the following inside your webview settings code:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

It successfully fixes the audio playback problem!

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem,
the solution worked for me is..
use Mediaplayer (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)  of Android for playing audio.
you can invoke function of android from javascript that you have written in HTML file..

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
--------------------------------
public class WebAppInterface {

    Context mContext;
    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

---------------------------
java sript code

<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

This way you invoke audio from Android code.

Answer (score 0):

Tag Audio just worked for me using `.loadUrl("https://webpage.html")`.

With `.loadData(htmlString, "text/html", null)` was showing Unsupported mime messages.