# The defference between Html5's object tag and audio tag when using data url

Tags: html, base64, web-audio-api, data-url, html-object

I need to play some music in html5 by using audio tag. The data is a base64 string(data:audio/wav;base64,xxxxxx) which is generated by the server.
Like image tag,it is said that audio tag can also use the data url,so I tried this:

```
<audio controls="controls" autobuffer="autobuffer" autoplay="autoplay" 
src="data:audio/midi;base64,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"/>
```

But I failed,nothing happened.
I searched for the result and find this:

[Play audio using base64 data in html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951438/play-audio-using-base64-data-in-html5/16784454#16784454)

There is a data url in the answer and I tried it,it played well.

So I think my base64 data is wrong,but when I put the data url into the browser address bar．It is played by some plugin!!Just the same performance like below(worked well but need to use a plugin):

```
<object width="50%" height="50%"type="audio/midi" data="data:audio/midi;base64,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"></object>
```

**So my question is: what is the difference between the two ways?**

I think there maybe some file header that should be contained when using audio tag,but I am not sure about it.

I find this link where the guy use the **header** template(RIFF<##>WAVEfmt \x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00<##><##>\x02\x00\x10\x00data<##>"):

[Playing audio from data:url google chrome mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130673/playing-audio-from-dataurl-google-chrome-mobile)

Appreciate for any help,thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Oh,so sorry to find out that most browsers do not support for the audio/midi data type,the object tag can play it because the plugin is more powerful.
And I found a midi.js here:

https://github.com/mudcube/MIDI.js

Answer (score 0):

Your mimetype (?) appears to be audio/midi instead of audio/wav. Also it is browser dependent. I used the same type of code, except that I converted an audio/wav (*.wav) to Base64. Using audio/wav and the Base64 converted (http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) data I could play the audio.

Also autobuffer is not recognized in HTML5, perhaps it's the quirk of VS 2013 Express for web where I tested. I took a audio file, extension *.wav and converted it into Base64 and plugged it into your code (using audio/wav) and it played well in Mozilla  Firefox.

Here is how IE 11, Safari 5.1.7 and Mozilla 26.0 display page with an audio tag:

http://hodentek.blogspot.com/2014/03/internet-explorer-11-cannot-play-audio.html

Here is the code to convert to Base64 and back:
http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/vb-net/encodingdecoding-web-service-web-service-provider/